Extend (monkey patch) 3rd party class in multiple places
I'm using a 3rd party library (Ibis, but it's not specific to Ibis). Functions from this library return objects of class X, which I want to extend with my methods pretty much everywhere I use Ibis itself. Usage example:
import ibis
from ibis_extensions import method1, method2, method3 # these I write myself
# monkeypatching every method, every time:
ibis.classX.method1 = method1
ibis.classX.method2 = method2
ibis.classX.method3 = method3

## I usually don't instantiate class X manually
obj1 = ibis.builtin_function1() # returns classX
obj2 = ibis.builtin_function2() # returns classX

## So that now I can use my methods
obj1.method3()
obj2.method2()

Above works, but it's excessive boilerplate: one line per method, per file (compare with how you can import multiple functions with a single line).
How do you deal with this situation? Is the best solution to modify Ibis's source code?
